# CSS Transition effect doesn't work on Chrome

Tags: cross-browser, css-transitions

So i'm creating a navbar (with Twitter Bootstrap) and pick a color for it, and set it to slightly different color when certain element are hovered. but the problem is, the transition doesn't seem to work on chrome, it's working on IE and Firefox so far. any ideas? here's the css transition code (i put it in the normal state, not on :hover):

```
-webkit-transition: All .50s ease-out;
-moz-transition: All .50s ease-out;
-o-transition: All .50s ease-out;
-ms-transition: All .50s ease-out;
transition: All .50s ease-out;
```

the color css is like this, if somehow needed:

```
background-color: hsl(0, 86%, 24%) !important;
background-repeat: repeat-x;
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#ed1b1b", endColorstr="#710808");
background-image: -khtml-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ed1b1b), to(#710808));
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ed1b1b, #710808);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ed1b1b, #710808);
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #ed1b1b), color-stop(100%, #710808));
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ed1b1b, #710808);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ed1b1b, #710808);
background-image: linear-gradient(#ed1b1b, #710808);
border-color: #710808 #710808 hsl(0, 86%, 17%);
color: #fff !important;
text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.46);
```

Comment: Can you post a demo of the problem ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jWkaT/ it runs fine in jsfiddle, but not in my actual code